# i need a C# library about strict HTML validation and filtering

Tags: c#, html, validation, filtering

i need a C# library about strict HTML validation and filtering

Comment: I guess these types of comments are unnecessary. Because I know some people are not converse in English, though they use stackoverflow.So my idea is that stackoverflow is a place for answer seekers.. Not for critics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Atwood posted some code for HTML tag filtering and sanitizing a while back. From your brief description it sounds like something you might want to look into.

http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001172.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any such thing exists, but it doesn't seem like it would be that hard to do a validation API that utilizes the w3C validator behind the scenes.

What kind of filtering are you talking about? Your question is very vague...